# faye ruby client is not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, faye

I am using faye on my Rails 2.1 app. And after testing and fixing many things `faye ruby client` is not working.

This is my server code.

```
require 'faye'

server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45)


EM.run {
  thin = Rack::Handler.get('thin')
  thin.run(server, :Port => 9292)

  server.bind(:subscribe) do |client_id, channel|
    puts "[  SUBSCRIBE] #{client_id} -> #{channel}"
  end

  server.bind(:unsubscribe) do |client_id, channel|
    puts "[UNSUBSCRIBE] #{client_id} -> #{channel}"
  end

  server.bind(:disconnect) do |client_id|
    puts "[ DISCONNECT] #{client_id}"
  end
}
```

This is my client side JS code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
    client.subscribe("/faye/new_chats", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

This is ruby client code.

```
EM.run do
      client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:9292/faye')
      publication = client.publish("/faye/new_chats", {
          "user" => "ruby-logger",
          "message" => "Got your message!"
      })
      publication.callback do
        puts "[PUBLISH SUCCEEDED]"
      end
      publication.errback do |error|
        puts "[PUBLISH FAILED] #{error.inspect}"
      end
    end
```

Server, JS is working fine. But Ruby client code is not working. If i write it without **EM** it shows me the error that `Event Machine not initialized`. If i write it in `EM` it works but haults the ruby process. If i put `EM.stop` at the end of client code, it executes but do not publish the message.

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally used HTTP not the Ruby Faye client as described in railscasts episode 260.

```
require 'net/http'
    message = {:channel => '/faye/new_chats', :data => self.text, :ext => {:auth_token => FAYE_TOKEN}}
    uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:9292/faye")
    Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :message => message.to_json)
```

It solves my problem.

NOTE: This solution only works with HTTP but not with HTTPS. If any one find a solution for HTTPS plz update me.

Answer (score 11):

You were almost there... You just needed to stop the EM event loop in your callbacks, like this:

```
EM.run do
  client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:9292/faye')
  publication = client.publish("/faye/new_chats", {
    "user" => "ruby-logger",
    "message" => "Got your message!"
  })
  publication.callback do
    puts "[PUBLISH SUCCEEDED]"
    EM.stop_event_loop
  end
  publication.errback do |error|
    puts "[PUBLISH FAILED] #{error.inspect}"
    EM.stop_event_loop
  end
end
```

Comment: I wish I could give you 10 more points! You really helped me on this, thanks!