# Unable to publish message with Faye Ruby client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye

First off, I've already look at:

[faye ruby client is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572150/faye-ruby-client-is-not-working)

I tried the recommendations and its still not working for me.

Heres my code:

```
def broadcast(channel, data=nil, &block)
  return if Rails.env.test?

  if data.nil? && block_given?
    data = capture(&block)
  end

  client = Faye::Client.new(APP_CONFIG['faye_url'])
  client.publish(channel, data)
end
```

I tried using Net::HTTP.post_form and the server froze with no errors or warnings or anything.  I've tried putting it into an EM.run block with no luck.  I can publish to Faye with curl just fine and its sent on to subscribers but for some reason the ruby client just isn't working.

I'm using faye-rails, ruby 1.9.3 and rails 2.3.13.

The server is behind nginx, I tried both the ngnix ip/port and the thin ip/port.  Still didn't work.

It works fine in development, just not in production.

**Update:**

I disabled both WebSockets and EventSource to force it to use long polling so it would work through ngnix without any errors.

It is also running as rack middleware so it shouldn't need any additional ports.

Comment: Is there any kind of firewall? If there is, you need to enable the port faye uses.

Comment: Updated with details to hopefully answer your questions.